# How run the Apache Zookeeper server as Background service in Windows

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I was able to run the *Zookeeper* server from command prompt on *Windows* .

Today I would like it to run as a background service instead and also start automatically upon OS boot.

I was able to create the service using below command.

```
sc.exe create ZookeeperService binPath= “C:\zookeeper\apache-zookeeper-3.5.5\bin\zkServer.cmd”
```

[image: Service Created]

… but it is not started and an the following error appears:
[image: Error]

Then how should I run Zookeeper server as an auto started service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, and using [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/download) was the only solution that worked for me.

```
sc.exe create
```

... does not work for batch files, because it does not implement the windows services interface like a .exe-file.

**Possible solutions:**

- [nssm.exe](https://nssm.cc/download) (my preferred solution).
- [SRVANY.EXE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/137890/how-to-create-a-user-defined-service)
- Create a new scheduled task via command prompt using [Schktasks.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/de-ch/help/814596/how-to-use-schtasks-exe-to-schedule-tasks-in-windows-server-2003)
- Create a new scheduled task via PowerShell using [ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Thank you for replay. I am able to do with nssm.

Comment: I went to the [nssm website](https://nssm.cc/download), and found that the latest release is 2014-08-31, which is concerning.

Comment: Warning: If you are using Zookeeper for Kafka on windows, I would like to mention the following: It is recommended to use Kafka on windows only for development purposes. Kafka is not well supported on windows (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#os). Unfortunately, this is not clearly shown at Apache. So you only recognize that when you see that the log cleaner does not run smoothly under windows due to authorization problems which shut down the broker. (ticket from 2013: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194)